# Insert entry into article field (elementselect?) on a user, with the "onBeforeSaveEntry" hook

Tags: plugin-development, entries, users, array, hook

I'm having a hard time inserting new content into an elementselect field for a user.

Here's the code I'm working on so far, inside a custom plugin init()

```
parent::init();
craft()->on('entries.onBeforeSaveEntry', function(Event $event) {
    $entry = $event->params['entry'];
    $isNew = $event->params['isNewEntry'];

    if ($isNew) {
        $user = craft()->users->getUserById($entry['authorId']);

        $focusList = $user->getContent()->focusList;

        if (!is_array($focusList)) {
            $focusList = array();
        }
        array_push($focusList, $entry);
        $user->getContent()->focusList = $focusList;

        craft()->users->saveUser($user);

    }
});
```

I'm tring to add a "onBeforeSaveEntry" hook, that first checks if the entry is new.

If it is, add the entry to the authors "focusList" (an article field without limits)

But I can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

The error message I'm stuck with so far:

```
"CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" is the error message I'm battling
```

Comment: Tried to change the hook to "entries.onSaveEntry", and the error message turns into "var_export does not handle circular references"

Answer (score 2):

Sweet, solved it.

Changed the line

```
array_push($focusList, $entry);
```

to

```
array_push($focusList, $entry->id);
```

and it worked! :D

EDIT: NOPE, it did not fully work. This hook overwrites all the other entries, leaving only the most recent inside the list.

This code does work, without overwriting:

```
parent::init();
craft()->on('entries.onSaveEntry', function(Event $event) {
    $entry = $event->params['entry'];
    $isNew = $event->params['isNewEntry'];

    if ($isNew) {
        $user = craft()->users->getUserById($entry['authorId']);
        $focusList = $user->getFieldValue('focusList');
        $values = [];


        foreach ($focusList as $focusEntry) {
            array_push($values, $focusEntry->id);
        }

        array_push($values, $entry->id);


        $user->setContentFromPost(array(
            'focusList' => $values
         ));
        craft()->users->saveUser($user);
    }
});
```